# how to pass dynamically generated value everytime with groovy script in Soap UI (for REST API) - Responce is in json inside CDATA

Tags: soapui

currenly have extracted value from "GET" test case and want to pass that to "PUT" request (in body).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AlWA.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as text ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format »» code/errors/data as an image » nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value as a test-case property:

```
// You'll have to add an 'idProperty' property yourself against the test case
def String id = json.entities.id
testRunner.TC_1.setPropertyValue("idProperty", id)
```

Then, use the property in the next request wherever you like with:

```
${#TestCase#idProperty}
```

See [Property Expansion](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/property-expansion.html) for more details.